# Separating a column into multiple columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use Pandas to load datasets and display them in tabular form. But I'm not sure why it can't be separated using delimiters. Does anyone know?

This is the output I got:
[image: This is the output got by me.]

My expected output is something like this:
[image]

The dataset that I used: https://www.kaggle.com/tunguz/big-five-personality-test

Comment: it loads fine for me using your code: `df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', delimiter='\t')`

Comment: what's your `pd.__version__`?

Comment: It's 1.2.3 for my Pandas version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments this works for me.  One way to avoid manual downloading issues is to automate download

1. `pip3 install kaggle`
2. place **kaggle.json** as directed by CLI
3. can then use following code to download Kaggle data in jupyter

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys
from pathlib import Path
if not Path.cwd().joinpath("IPIP-FFM-data-8Nov2018/data-final.csv").exists():
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + "datasets download tunguz/big-five-personality-test --unzip".split(" ")
    kaggle.cli.main()
    
pd.read_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath("IPIP-FFM-data-8Nov2018/data-final.csv"), sep="\t")
```